# Excel Question: How do I approach compartmentalising and summing/extracting data for instances where specific criteria is met?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I had the following data on row 2 in the range in Excel (`A2:L2`):

```
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2 I2 J2 K2 L2
|31|28|00|00|07|00|00|00|05|31|10|00|
```

What would be the best approach to sum every instance where there are values greater than 0 (either a single value or consecutive values).

For example (`A2+B2`) would be summed as they are consecutively greater than 0 but this would not continue as `C2 = 0` giving us our first instance. But `E2` would be considered as it is greater than 0 making the second instance, followed by the sum of (`I2+J2+K2`) being the third instance.

Where I am stuck is that (`E2`) and (`I2+J2+K2`) also needs to be summed separately as they too are greater than 0 or consecutively greater than 0.

The method/formula should return all instances where numbers are consecutively greater than 0. i.e. `(A2+B2)=59`, `(E2)=7` & `(I2+J2+K2)=46` separately.

Essentially, I need a robust formula/s or method that could return every instance where SUM of datapoints are >0 OR consecutively >0, separately.

NOTE: There will be multiple rows where these datapoints vary in the position and size of "instances" (2,3 or 4 numbers consecutively).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried:

```
=SUM(IF((A2:L2>0)*(A2:L2<>0), INDEX(A2:L2, MATCH(1, (A2:L2>0)*(A2:L2<>0), 0)):INDEX(A2:L2, MATCH(1, (A2:L2=0)*ROW(A2:L2), 0)-1)))
```

No luck - I get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky. I think scan might work like this:

```
=LET(data,A2:L2,rollSum,SCAN(0,data,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=0,0,a+c))),FILTER(rollSum,(data>0)*(HSTACK(DROP(data,,1),0)=0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an empty cell `M2`, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B4`:

```
=TOCOL(IFS(A2:L2*(B2:M2=0),SCAN(0,A2:L2,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+y,0)))),3)
```

If `M2` can't be used, you can `HSTACK()` a trailing zero:

```
=TOCOL(IFS(A2:L2*(HSTACK(B2:L2,0)=0),SCAN(0,A2:L2,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+y,0)))),3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`=MAP(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",1,",00",A2:L2),",00",,1),LAMBDA(x,SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(x,",",,1))))`